# Main differences/features among the most known NoSQL systems

Tags: mongodb, cassandra, redis, couchdb, nosql

I have no experience with NoSQL database systems but if I would have to choose one of the most known (MongoDb, Cassandra, CouchDb, Redis), can someone describe the relevant main features/differences of every one? Is there anything I should know with regards to their capabilities that might affect the choice of NoSQL system I use>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redis is a **key-value store**. You can usually insert a primitive value (int, string, bool), or an array of primitives under a single key. Retrieval of data is usually limited to query by key. These are the most basic NoSQL databases.

Cassandra is a **column-family store**. It's similar to a key-value store, but supports nesting of key-value pairs up to about four levels deep. Querying is limited to query by key and map-reduce functions. This type of database has a rather difficult data model ([does 'supercolumn' ring any bells?](http://arin.me/blog/wtf-is-a-supercolumn-cassandra-data-model)) and is highly specialized for extremely large amounts of data.

MongoDB and CouchDB are both **document databases**. They both store JSON documents, which aren't restricted by a schema, giving you a lot of flexibility. The database allows you to query the contents of these documents, which makes it very easy to retrieve data, compared to other types of NoSQL databases. Map-reduce functions are also supported.

Martin Fabik's answer contains some good links to comparisons of MongoDB and CouchDB.

Ayende has a series of blog posts called [That No SQL Thing](http://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Aayende.com+intitle%3A%22that+no+sql+thing%22) that handles each of these types. It's a good introduction to the NoSQL concept, the different types of NoSQL databases and how to query each of them. I highly recommend you read his articles on the database types I mentioned above, they are very instructive!

Answer (score 1):

I was lately doing some research on this topic. I can post you some links..

Nice [categorization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoSQL) of NoSQL DBs.

[Comparing](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Comparing+Mongo+DB+and+Couch+DB) MongoDB and CouchDB

Comparing MongoDB, CouchDB and RavenDB [Part1](http://weblogs.asp.net/britchie/archive/2010/08/12/document-databases.aspx)
Comparing MongoDB, CouchDB and RavenDB [Part2](http://weblogs.asp.net/britchie/archive/2010/08/17/document-databases-compared-mongodb-couchdb-and-ravendb.aspx)

I was pretty impressed by RavenDB. It supports also transactions and triggers,but the licensing is not so friendly.

Some [arguments](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2010/05/13/why-raven-db.aspx) why RavenDB from Ayende (creator of RavenDB)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other links, take a look at the [Survey of Distributed Databases](http://nosqlpedia.com/wiki/Survey_distributed_databases) as well as this what if that takes a look at the characteristics of other NoSQL databases and how they respond - [MongoDB and Foursquare - What If?].

Finally, [NoSQLSummer] has a lot of good papers describing the various offerings out there and the theoretical underpinnings of each one.