# NoSQL graph database for AI

Tags: nosql, graph-databases

I am trying to build a distributed AI. It works on graph and most of its problem relies on the database.
I need an SQL database that supports graphs ( or I can make it support)
I need node locking or atomic increment support
Most importantly I need persistant keys for every node and link in the graph. Most graph databases don't give a persistant key.
I have tried some of the databases like Neo4j but it lacks persistant key and also I can't change a link's first or seconds node.
My writes and reads are nearly equal and I am adding more node and links during runtime so Pregel like graph processing don't work for me.
Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: look at this for help

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3735784/how-to-decide-which-nosql-technology-to-use?rq=1

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4237687/main-differences-features-among-the-most-known-nosql-systems?rq=1

Comment: by persistent you mean that the database is append-only? or something like that?